# Dynamically change nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to put a value in a JSON with this code:

```
result = {}    
result[idHour] = {};
result[idHour][date.minute()] = req.body.generated;
```

idHour is a variable I have defined earlier. 
I expect a JSON like this:

```
{
"18": [ "40": 1000]
}
```

If req.body.generated is 1000, idHour is 18 and date.minute() is 40, but I get this:

```
{
"18": [ null ]
}
```

I have searched for other ways to do this, yet I can't find anything. Is there a way which works for changing/adding values in a nested JSON?

Comment: The way you are attempting to access it is that of a 2D array.  You need a variable that functions as a pointer to result[idHour], then do variable[date.minute()] = ...

Comment: @Vizkos Do you mean like this?

    `result[idHour] = {};`
    
`var hour = result[idHour];`
    `hour['minute-' + date.minute()] = req.body.generated;`

I have tried this way, yet the result is the same.

Comment: Do you specifically need the array or could you use nested JSON? If not you could do `result = { idhour : {date.minute() : req.body.generated}};` Then access them with dot operator.

Comment: @GlennHolland Using nested JSON is not a problem. The thing is that idHour and date.minute() are variables and I think that you can't access dynamic JSON fields with dot operator.

Comment: @Ives could you not give them keys? `result = { "id" : idHour, "values" : {"minute" : date.minute(), "generated" :  req.body.generated}};`  That way you could have dot operator access.

Comment: If you are trying to get it to be exactly like what you have, then that is not possible, because it looks like you are trying to use properties in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you meant date.getMinutes()?
This seems to do the trick for me...

```
<script>
var idHour = "18";
var generated = 1000;
var date = new Date();
result = {};
result[idHour] = {};
result[idHour][date.getMinutes()] = generated;
document.write(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
</script>
```

The result was:
    { "18": { "35": 1000 } }

Also date.getMinutes() doesn't return a string, so your JSON stringifier may want you to convert it with toString().