# How to change nested JSON value using stringify replacer?

Tags: javascript, json, object, stringify

I use `JSON.stringify(value, replacer)` to mask sensitive data in JSON object.

```js
const inputJsonObject = 
     { 
       "id": "uniqueId",
       "value": "objectData",
       "user": {
         "password": "qwerty"
       }
     };

const hideDataMethod = JSON.stringify(inputJsonObject, (key, value) => {
  const dataToHide = ['id', 'user.password'];

  return dataToHide.indexOf(key) === -1 ? value : 'xxx';
});

console.log(hideDataMethod);
```

How to get to `user.password` value? The above solution works for `id` but doesn't for password.

Comment: Why JSON at all? Just iterate through the object and replace the values directly. There are a bunch of questions that will have a solution on how to do exactly that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically change nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930689/dynamically-change-nested-json)

Comment: because password is `password` not `user.password`

Comment: Note that what you've called `inputJsonObject` is not JSON, it's just an object. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. (Similarly, `hideDataMethod` isn't a method, it's a string.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work for `password` because you're looking for a property called `"user.password"`, but there is none; the property's name is `password`, not `user.password`. (It's a property on an object that's referenced by the `user` property on another object, but that has nothing to do with the property name.) If you remove the `user.` part of that, it will work. Beware that doing it removes **all** `id` and `password` properties from **all** objects in the object graph being stringified:

```js
const inputObject = {
    "id": "uniqueId",
    "value": "objectData",
    "user": {
        "password": "qwerty"
    }
};

const dataToHide = ["id", "password"];
const json = JSON.stringify(inputObject, (key, value) => {
    return dataToHide.indexOf(key) === -1 ? value : "xxx";
});

console.log(json);
```

*(I also changed the name of a couple of variables that had misleading names.)*

But I would sanitize it *before* converting it to JSON rather than during:

```
const tmp = {
    ...inputObject,
    id: "xxx",
    user: {
        ...inputObject.user,
        password: "xxx",
    }
};
const json = JSON.stringify(tmp);
```